# How to match method with a complex generic parameter using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to call a EntityFramework method using reflection.
The signature of the method is

```
DbCollectionEntry<TEntity, TElement> Collection<TElement> 
(Expression <Func<TEntity, ICollection <TElement>>> navigationProperty) where TElement : class
```

where TEntity is a type parameter of the class. How can construct a type which which will equal `Expression <Func<TEntity, ICollection <TElement>>>` so I can find the right overload of the method? I tried  `typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(Func<,>) });` which displays the same in the debugger but  doesn't match by equality. Once I  have the method how do I call it? I managed to find the method by excluding the one with a string parameter but I still want find out how to match the method properly. I tried invoking the method using `method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyType)).Invoke(context.Entry(t), new[] { lambda });` but I get the exception "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true." Here's what I have so far

```
var collectionMethod = typeof(DbEntityEntry<>)
    .GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Collection")
        .Select(m => new { Method = m, Params = m.GetParameters(), Args = m.GetGenericArguments() })
        .Where(x => x.Args.Length == 1 && x.Params[0].ParameterType != typeof(string))
        .Select(x => x.Method)
        .First();

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Trade, ICollection<TradeLeg>>>(prop, param);

// this fails
var o = collectionMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TradeLeg))
    .Invoke(context.Entry(t), new[] { lambda });
```

Comment: What you want to achieve by that ?

Comment: @Piotr - I was experimenting with calling various  method with dynamically constructed arguments, I probably don't need to call this one dynamically but I decided to try it as exercise. I want to call other methods with similar signatures.

Comment: Plaease give some very simple example of usage :) What the exisiting method looks like right now and how you want to create new dynamic one (how should it be different) - hard to imageine. For now it looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Piotr - I have updated my question to show what I have so far. As I mentioned I have no real need to call this particular function but as I was working through it I found there was a gap in my knowledge in that I  didn't know match the generic type so I want to know how to do it for the sake of my own education and future use more than anything else :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var collectionMethod = typeof(DbEntityEntry<>)
```

This line condemns you to a failure, because the method will be looked for on the generic definition, not on the constructed type you use. The method must be identified on the concrete type, not on the definition, in order to call it. Based on your code, I assume the correct expression is `typeof(DbEntityEntry<Trade>)`.